# Python 3.3: All possible combinations of list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have list like this:

```
[['one', 'two', 'three', ...], ['a', 'b', ...], ['left', 'right'] ...]
```

and I need to create all possible combinations of that items and put it into string like:

```
"one|a|left"
"one|a|right"
"one|b|left"
"one|b|right"
"two|a|left"
"two|a|right"
"two|b|left"
...
```

what is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: Did you check https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations ?

Comment: yes I try itertools but it do not work way I need

Comment: Obviously, I got the wrong function…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product
lst = [['one', 'two', 'three'], ['a', 'b'], ['left', 'right']]
print(list(product(*lst)))
```

Verify that it does what you want:

```
[('one', 'a', 'left'), ('one', 'a', 'right'), ('one', 'b', 'left'), ('one', 'b', 'right'), ('two', 'a', 'left'), ('two', 'a', 'right'), ('two', 'b', 'left'), ('two', 'b', 'right'), ('three', 'a', 'left'), ('three', 'a', 'right'), ('three', 'b', 'left'), ('three', 'b', 'right')]
```

To produce the desired strings you described:

```
["|".join([p, q, r]) for p, q, r in product(*lst)]
```

Output:

```
['one|a|left',
 'one|a|right',
 'one|b|left',
 'one|b|right',
 'two|a|left',
 'two|a|right',
 'two|b|left',
 'two|b|right',
 'three|a|left',
 'three|a|right',
 'three|b|left',
 'three|b|right']
```

Comment: Why so long? I would prefer `map( "|".join, product(*lst) )`.

Comment: @Arpegius: In Python 3: use `list(map(..))`.